# Compact set in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $H$ be a complete metric space, we equip $H$ with the induced metric norm. Let $S$ be a set of $H$.

Assume that for any $\epsilon>0$, we can find compact set $K_\epsilon$, such that $S$ is contained in a $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $K_\epsilon$.

**Q** Can we say $\bar S$, i.e. the closure of $S$, is compact?

Comment: What notion of "dimension" are you using?  What do you mean by "the induced metric norm"?

Answer (score 0):

Answer assuming completeness: the hypothesis is very confusing but the result is true in any complete metric space. Since compact sets are totally bounded, the hypothesis tells you that $S$ is totally bounded. Hence its closure is compact.